# Marshal.load a string

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to deserialize a hash from a string:

```
names = '{foo:"bar"}'
@names_hash = Marshal.load(names)
```

but I get a TypeError:

```
TypeError: incompatible marshal file format (can't be read)
    format version 4.8 required; 123.111 given
```

According to the docs Marshal.load should accept a String. Why am I getting the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the output of an IRB session:

```
irb(main):005:0> a = {"foo" => "bar"}
=> {"foo"=>"bar"}
irb(main):006:0> Marshal.dump(a)
=> "\004\b{\006\"\bfoo\"\bbar"
```

What you're doing looks more like JSON to me, than Marshaling.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been names = "{foo:"bar"}". I was looking for a way to store and load hashes in string form. Looks like Marshal is not human readable and it would be better if I did some manual string operations.

Comment: JSON is the human readable alternative. Why don't you go with that?